# Installing glyphs on powerlevel9k

Tags: font-awesome, zsh, glyph

I've installed powerlevel9k on zshell. How do I install glyphs for my terminal?

I've tried installing font-awesome and I've set `POWERLEVEL9K_MODE='awesome-fontconfig'` but it still doesn't work.

Also what is `awesome-fontconfig`? If it's a config file, do I have to create one after I download font-awesome? Where do I put this config file?

Comment: You may install awesome terminal fonts from https://github.com/gabrielelana/awesome-terminal-fonts. Follow your OS specific instructions, then tell powelevel9k to use those glyphs by setting `POWERLEVEL9K_MODE='awesome-fontconfig'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

1. Install the font.
2. Configure your terminal emulator to use that font.
3. Tell P9k what font configuration to use.

It sounds like you've done steps 1 and 3, but perhaps not step 2? More information is on the P9k wiki: https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k/wiki/Install-Instructions#step-2-install-a-powerline-font

Comment: I'm using Adobe Source Code Pro in my terminal emulator (gnome terminal). So if I install font-awesome, do I have to change my terminal's font to 'font-awesome'? After that I tell PK9 to use font-awesome config right?

Comment: I also use ASCP. I have my terminal using it, and have configured P9k to `awesome-fontconfig` mode, and it works great. Give that a shot.

Comment: Yes, I've figured out it works fine now. Thanks for your help, appreciate it!